# SCIM PUT default value

Tags: scim

We have question about the SCIM standard and its interpretation around handling of omitted values in the PUT operation:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644

"readWrite, writeOnly  Any values provided SHALL replace the existing
attribute values.

```
  Attributes whose mutability is "readWrite" that are omitted from
  the request body MAY be assumed to be not asserted by the client.
  The service provider MAY assume that any existing values are to be
  cleared, or the service provider MAY assign a default value to the
  final resource representation.  Service providers MAY take into
  account whether or not a client has access to, or understands, all
  of the resource's attributes when deciding whether non-asserted
  attributes SHALL be removed or defaulted.  Clients that want to
  override a server's defaults MAY specify "null" for a
  single-valued attribute, or an empty array "[]" for a multi-valued
  attribute, to clear all values."
```

In there it refers to "a default value". Does default value have to be a singular value? Would it be against the standard to define the default value to be the value that the resource currently has, i.e. field keeps the current value?

Regards,
LT

Answer (score 1):

I interpret "a default value" to mean a single, likely static or mechanically generated value. The presence of "a" before the term "default value" pushes me that way and eliminates most or all interpretations that would allow for more than one possible default value per attribute.

Am I correct in assuming that the scenario you're thinking of is surrounding if a required attribute containing a value is omitted from a PUT request? If so, this bit from RFC 7644 3.5.1 is what you'd want to follow:

> > If an attribute is "required", clients MUST specify the attribute in
> > the PUT request.

Any attribute that isn't allowed to be null/empty should be marked as required in your schema. If a PUT request doesn't include required attributes, a 400/Bad Request error response should be returned with a scimType value of invalidValue, as described in RFC 7644 section 3.12.

If the situation is "it can be empty, but once populated it can be updated with a new value but not cleared", then I don't think there's a combination of schema properties that represent that in the current SCIM spec.

Comment: Zollnerd, thanks for your answer. The problem we have is that we have a scim user schema which has covers a lot of the fields we have in our system for a user. Most of the fields are not required. We provide service to many customers and for most of them, they only have some of the fields in their system. We know that we can tell our customers that if they want to use PUT, they should do a GET and any fields that they don't have in their system, they should send the value they got in the GET. We support patch so they can use that. But the problem is that sometime it is not under their control.

Comment: The "not under their control" thing sounds like a business problem if anything - is the issue that they didn't write the client making the PUT call?

The SCIM spec's section on PUT is pretty clear with these lines:
>>   HTTP PUT is used to replace a resource's attributes.  For example,
   clients that have previously retrieved the entire resource in advance
   and revised it MAY replace the resource using an HTTP PUT.  


>>   As the operation's intent is to replace all attributes..

Comment: Yes, while our clients can use our SCIM api directly, many of them use the SCIM integration that's provided by their user directory system to push user updates into our system. Then the customer may not have control over whether PUT or PATCH is used to push user updates to our system, and if PUT is used exactly how that behaves, or we wind up having to figure out exactly how to configure their scim integration of their user directory system, if possible, to not have PUT over writing values with blanks on fields they don't have in their user directory.

Comment: As covered above, I think it'd be a stretch to interpret the spec in a way that gets you the outcome you want. There's the bit about "Service providers MAY take into
  account whether or not a client has access to, or understands, all
  of the resource's attributes when deciding whether non-asserted
  attributes SHALL be removed or defaulted.". If the attributes are just entirely outside of the scope of what any connected identity system is going to manage, consider not granting read/write access to those attributes for the tokens provided to IDPs - or at least those IDPs..

Comment: The "they have no control" piece is only partially true, since they can choose to not use that specific SCIM service making the suboptimal PUT calls. That then puts you in a battle with the identity platform, though, since they may change either the IDP or the problematic app (yours).

Comment: Working through the pile of MAYs and SHALLs in the quoted piece of the SCIM spec in your original post, this piece stands out: 

"when deciding whether non-asserted attributes SHALL be removed or defaulted."  

I could see different ways to read that - you MAY take into account <conditions> when deciding if you'll do (one of remove or default), or you MAY take into account .. if you'll do either of them. Given the "SHALL be removed or defaulted", and the numerous mentions of "PUT is for replacing" - I think it's a choice between one of those two, with no third "do something else" option.

Comment: TL;DR: I understand your problem, but it's a problem with the calls made by the client that isn't really solvable in a way that complies with the spec. Your best bet on a solution is probably to not grant ability to read/write those attributes at all, at least to the problematic clients, if that makes sense based on the purpose of the attributes. That or go yell at the company that developed the client to start using PATCH.